# CSM Package Not Found

Tags: ros, catkin-make, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've got an issue compiling laser_scan_matcher. When running catkin_make I get the following error:

-- checking for module 'csm'
-- package 'csm' not found
Cmake error

Now I've built csm and installed it. What else do I need to do to get catkin to find it?

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229488/csm-package-not-found/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-18**:
How did you install the `csm` package?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-18**:
My base ROS workspace is ~/ros_ws/src
Installed csm src into  ~/ros_ws/src/csm and ran install_quickstart.sh  which successfully compiled it all and "installed" it

That installed it to:
~/ros_ws/src/csm/deploy

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-18**:
What operating system are you using?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-18**:
Did you `source  ~/ros_ws/src/csm/deploy/setup.bash`?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-18**:
This is on a raspberry pi (hence the building everything) re: source - there is no  ~/ros_ws/src/csm/deploy/setup.bash file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like `laser_scan_matcher` [uses  pkg-config](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/blob/indigo/laser_scan_matcher/CMakeLists.txt#L21) to find the `csm` headers and libraries.

You probably need to set the `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in your environment, adding the directory containing the `csm.pc` file installed with `csm`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-21**:
Cheers sir that has done the trick!! (Now it can't find csm header files - shall try and persuade it otherwise :) )

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-21**:
That should have resolved both header and library locations. What does `pkg-config --cflags csm` print?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-21**:
Comes back with -I/usr/include/cairo -I/home/pi/ros_ws/install/include

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-21**:
Seems OK. Are the headers in fact there?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-21**:
Just gotten around to checking this - so you were correct - the headers weren't there. Simply copied them into that dir and it's all complied! I now have - after some faff - LSM running on a Pi 2. Shall write all this up as a how-to...

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-21**:
Copying the headers should not have been necessary. The `csm` install should have created a `csm.pc` that points to the right place. If you write this up, try to figure out what when wrong with that.

**Comment by [DM2](https://answers.ros.org/users/27473/dm2/) on 2016-07-14**:
After installation (and exporting the pkg-config to `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`), and checking the headers are installed where they should be, I try to `catkin_make_isolated` but `failed to process package csm, no env.sh generated at /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/csm/env.sh`

**Comment by [DM2](https://answers.ros.org/users/27473/dm2/) on 2016-07-14**:
full command is `ros_catkin_ws $ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --force-cmake`. I think it's somehow interpreting csm as a package.

EDIT: I added --install to the command and it seems to have passed the make :/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good day to all. I have repeatedly faced with this problem: installation laser_scan_matcher for ROS kinetic. To solve this problem on three different machines, and finally I decided to write an algorithm that helped me. Probably, it is not very correct, as I replace the relative path to the libraries in the absolute, but nevertheless it - it works for me.

Now the algorithm itself. In the future, I mean that the package is the full path to my catkin_ws is: /home/edward/catkin_ws

### Algorithm

1.first install the package csm itself in directory /catkin_ws/src: git clone https://github.com/AndreaCensi/csm.git
and package scan_tools: git clone https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools.git

2.in /catkin_ws do catkin_make

3.open: nano ~/.bashrc and add to end of file as a variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH tssm.pk path to the file. In my case, this line looks like this:

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/pkg-config
and make: source ~/.bashrc

4.Next, you must explicitly register in five file path to the header files:

1. in file    /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/scan_tools/laser_scan_matcher/include/laser_scan_matcher/laser_scan_matcher.h   replace #include '<'csm/csm_all.h'>' on #include '<'/home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/csm/csm_all.h'> (without apostrophes, of course)
2. in file /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/csm/laser_data_json.h replace json-c/json.h and json-c/json_more_utils.h on
   /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/lib/json-c/json.h and home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/lib/json-c/json_more_utils.h respectively
3. in file /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/csm/hsm/hsm_interface.h replace options/options.h on /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/lib/options/options.h
4. on file /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/csm/json_journal.h replace json-c/json.h and json-c/json_more_utils.h on
   /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/lib/json-c/json.h and /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/lib/json-c/json_more_utils.h  respectivetly
5. Lastly, in file /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/csm/math_utils_gsl.h replace egsl/egsl.h on /home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/lib/egsl/egsl.h

5.Finally, go to your /catkin_ws and do catkin_make

And, wow miracle - all gathered! I hope this spike curve method will help you :) Happy ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Edward](https://answers.ros.org/users/29319/edward/) with karma: 76 on 2017-02-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jinn](https://answers.ros.org/users/28820/jinn/) on 2017-03-09**:
You can also add thoes path to ~/.bashrc, like this: export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm/lib:/home/edward/catkin_ws/src/csm/sm

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-03-12**:
Maintainers of `scan_tools` and `csm` are [stuck at some problem in making a release of them](https://github.com/tork-a/csm-release/issues/3). If anyone can help that's great!

**Comment by [prasgane](https://answers.ros.org/users/26487/prasgane/) on 2018-01-10**:
I got an error saying "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "csm" with any of
the following names:
csmConfig.cmake
csm-config.cmake "
I thought the catkin could not find the package so I went ahead and followed your solution  but doesn't seem to fix it. Any suggestion?

**Comment by [Edward](https://answers.ros.org/users/29319/edward/) on 2018-01-11**:
Since recently the installation from the repository has been made correctly. At least for the kinetics. I do not have any problems with CSM anymore. Just enter in the terminal

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-navigation
```

if you have ros kinetic distro